# How to get number of options in dynamically (JSP) created <select> part, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I generate page with this:

```
<%List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
someList = SQL();%>
<select id=Select>
<% for (int i =0; i < someList.size(); i++) {   %>
    <option value=<%= someList.get(i) %>><%= someList.get(i) %></option>
<%} %>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="updateParagraph()">Update Paragraph!</button>
```

Ok this part is created on server using JSP, but now i want following code to be executed
on client side.

```
var counter=0;
function updateParagraph()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("paragraph"+counter);
    var y = document.getElementById("Select").value;
if (counter < 5)
{
    x.innerHTML = y;
    counter++
}
}
```

This as written here works, but the problem is i don't want to limit this to 5 paragraph changes. I need advice how to get number of option in < select>. As depending of SQL() there might be 5 or 55 options in select.

I hope you will understand question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the "length" property of the option list:

```
var optionCount = y.options.length;
```

*edit* oops "y" isn't the select element; it'd be like this:

```
var y = document.getElementById("Select");
var yvalue = y.value, ycount = y.options.length;
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

Use `options.length` of the select element

```
var counter=0;
function updateParagraph()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("paragraph"+counter);
    var y = document.getElementById("Select");
    if (counter < y.options.length)
    {
        x.innerHTML = y.value;
        counter++
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't know that there is that property :(.

Comment: On a side not i use eclipse and i don't get that suggested when i press Ctrl + space. Anyone know why?

Comment: From my experience JavaScript  intellisense is quite iffy